# Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty} \frac{n^3 - 5n^2 + \pi}{2n^5 - \sqrt{3}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Does $$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{n^3 - 5n^2 + \pi}{2n^5 - \sqrt{3}}$$
>
> converge?

**My attempt:**

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus\{0\}:\frac{n^3-5n^2 + \pi }{2n^5 -\sqrt{3}} = \frac{1}{n^2}\frac{1-5/n + \pi/n^2}{2- \sqrt{3}/n^5}$$

And because

$$\frac{1-5/n + \pi/n^2}{2- \sqrt{3}/n^5} \to \frac{1}{2}$$

there exists $n_0$ such that $\forall n > n_0: \left\vert \dfrac{1-5/n + \pi/n^2}{2- \sqrt{3}/n^5}  - \dfrac{1}{2}\right\vert < 1$

Hence, for $n \geq n_0$:

$$ \frac{1-5/n + \pi/n^2}{2- \sqrt{3}/n^5} < \frac{3}{2}$$

Thus: $$\frac{n^3-5n^2 + \pi }{2n^5 -\sqrt{3}} < \frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{n^2}$$

and for $n_1$ sufficiently large, the sequence of terms is positive (as both the numerator and the denumerator converge to $+ \infty$, so for $n$ large enough the numerator and denumerator are positive, and hence the quotient is positive).

Let $N :=  \max\{n_0,n_1\}$

Then, because $\sum\dfrac{1}{n^2}$ converges, we conclude using the comparison test that the series

$$\sum_{n > N}^{+ \infty} \frac{n^3-5n^2 + \pi }{2n^5 -\sqrt{3}}$$

converges, and hence, the given series converges.

Is this correct? (I tried to explain every single step). Do you have any comments? Is there an easier approach?

Comment: Perfectly fine! No comments. I don't think an easier approach as rigorous as this exist.

Comment: It depends on the level of detail expected. You can note that your series is $\sum_{n\geq 1} p(n)/q(n)$ where $p$ is of order $3$ and $q$ is order of $5$, so $p/q$ is of order $-2$ and anything of order $<-1$ converges.

Comment: I'd suggest using `^` for powers. Superscript numbers are very hard to read

Comment: I'm sorry. I do press this symbol but Linux makes it that way. Will pay more attention to it in the future.

Comment: You have also $\frac{n^3 - 5n^2 + \pi}{2n^5 - \sqrt{3}} \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$ because it is equivalent with $\pi n^2+\sqrt{3}\leq n^5+5n^4$ and right side grows faster (and for $n=1$ we have $\pi+\sqrt{3} \leq 4+2=6$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps,
\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{n^{3}-5n^{2}+\pi}{2n^{5}-\sqrt{3}}\right|&\leq\dfrac{n^{3}+5n^{3}+\pi n^{3}}{2n^{5}-\sqrt{3}n^{5}}\\
&=\dfrac{6+\pi}{2-\sqrt{3}}\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}.
\end{align*}

Comment: This is very elegant and extremely accessible without sacrificing rigour/detail.

Answer (score 1):

your general term is equivalent to $1/n^2$, so it converges.

Comment: Clearly the OP is not [yet] at a level of mathematical studies for which this would be an appropriate answer.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman: clearly the OP is quite at a level to understand this. He knows about the convergence of the Basel series and understands the comparison test and expression rework.

Comment: @Gustav: It is equivalent to $\dfrac1{\color{red}2n^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

A rational expression $\dfrac{P(n)}{Q(n)}$ is asymptotic to $\dfrac{p_p}{q_q}n^{p-q}$ where $p,q$ are the respective degrees and $p_p,q_q$ the leading coefficients. (You can check this by factoring out the powers $n^p$ and $n^q$ from the fraction.)

And as you know, the summation of $n^{p-q}$ converges for $p-q<-1$. The other terms can be neglected.